# CVS : How to get the list of modified/added files recursively in CVS

Tags: recursion, addition, commit, cvs

I would like to know how to get the modified/added files recursively in CVS.

i tried below command it works great. but i want to know is there any better command.

cvs -qn update | egrep 'M |A |U ' | awk '{print $2}'

It would be Great, if some one share the  script to display changed files(add/modified) and add(new) and commit(change).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly simpler command would be to avoid an entirely unnecessary pipeline process and just use the one `awk` filter:

```
cvs -qn update | awk '$1 ~ /[MAU]/ {print $2}'
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is more or less similar one.